# Launch Applications in WIndows using AppID and get the pid

Tags: windows, powershell, go, appx

I'm trying to launch Windows applications using their AppID such as `Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App` which I get by calling `Get-StartApps`

Currently I can launch the applications but can't get the correct PID

```golang
cmd = exec.Command("powershell", "start", `shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`)
err := cmd.Start()
fmt.Println(cmd.Process.Pid)
```

This returns the PID of powershell

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

Is there a way to launch the application by the AppID and still get the correct PID?

Comment: You can call the COM API but even then it will not give you the PID unless you capture it in a Job and even then, UWP hosts and other WinRT junk might get in the way...

Comment: @Anders I'll try that, tho not sure how to capture the PID in a job.

Comment: JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS

Comment: @mklement0 It works, but kinda inconstant, which you also said in your answer

Comment: Please see my update, which should now be robust. It turns out that the fact that Calculator only ever creates _one_ process per user session makes identifying the relevant process simple and, from what I can tell, reliable. Note that more work is required if you want to identify the new _window_ that gets created.

Comment: @mklement0 This works if I change Calculator to CalculatorApp. Tho looking up the names for each of the apps is not really a good solution. Tho it seems there is not real solution to this, so I'll give the accepted answer to you as it does work.

Comment: Thanks, @TaylorRamirez. Re `CalculatorApp`: that is curious, because on my Windows 10 machine it is definitely `Calculator` - are you on Windows 11? After launching Calculator, `(Get-Process *calc*).Name` returns `CalculatorApp` for you? In general, yes, searching by process name isn't ideal, but it's the best solution under the circumstances.

Comment: @mklement0 Yeah this test machine it Windows 11. You think MS would fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```golang
// Make PowerShell not only launch Calculator, but also
// determine and output its PID, as described in the next section.
out, _ := 
        exec.Command(
          `powershell.exe`, 
          `-NoProfile`, 
          `-Command`, 
          `Start-Process -ErrorAction Stop calculator: ; (Get-Process Calculator | Where-Object SessionId -eq (Get-Process -ID $PID).SessionId).ID`,
        ).Output()

// Parse stdout output, which contains the PID, into an int
var pid int
fmt.Sscanf(string(out), "%d\n", &pid)
```

---

- ***In principle*, you can pass `-PassThru` to PowerShell's `Start-Process` (`start`) cmd, which returns a process-info object that has an `.Id` property containing the launched process' PID**, and output the latter.
- **Unfortunately, with UWP / AppX applications *specifically*, such as Calculator, this does *not* work, which is a problem that exists in the underlying .NET APIs**, up to at least .NET 6.0 - see [GitHub issue #10996](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10996).

You can try the following **workaround**:

- Launch the AppX application with `Start-Process`, which indirectly creates a process whose name is `Calculator` (Windows 10) / `CalculatorApp` (Windows 11).

  - You can identify this name yourself if you run `(Get-Process *calc*).Name` after launching Calculator. `Get-Process *calc* | Select-Object Name, Path` would show the executable path too, but note that this executable should be considered an implementation detail and can *not* be invoked directly.
- Return the ID of that `Calculator` / `CalculatorApp` process. The fact that Calculator only ever creates *one* such process in a given user session actually makes identifying that process easy.

  - Note that this means that the PID of a *preexisting* Calculator process may be returned, which, however, *is* the correct one, because the *transient* process launched by `Start-Process` simply delegates creation of a new Calculator window to an existing process.
  - If you wanted to identify the newly created *window*, more work would be required: You'd have to enumerate the process' windows and identify the one with the highest z-order.

PowerShell code (note: in Windows 11, replace `Calculator` with `CalculatorApp`):

```bash
# Launch Calculator - which may reuse an existing instance and
# merely create a new *window* - and report the PID.
Start-Process -ErrorAction Stop calculator:
(Get-Process Calculator | Where-Object SessionId -eq (Get-Process -ID $PID).SessionId).ID
```

<sup>Note that I've used the URL scheme `calculator:` as a simpler way to launch Calculator.</sup>

Note:

- The `Where-Object SessionId -eq (Get-Process -ID $PID).SessionId` guards against mistakenly considering potential `Calculator` processes created by *other users* in *their own sessions* (`Get-Process` returns *all* processes running on the local machine, across all user sessions). Filtering by `.SessionID`, i.e. by the active user session (window station), prevents this problem.

As a PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) call:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process -ErrorAction Stop calculator: ; (Get-Process Calculator | Where-Object SessionId -eq (Get-Process -ID $PID).SessionId).ID"
```